# Failover clustering validation report error: Validate Active Directory Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-clustering

I am deploying failover clustering on windows server 2016 enterprise

When validate configuration, failover cluster validation report an error

At system configuration > Validate Active Directory Configuration

This is error message:

```
Connectivity to a writable domain controller from node EC2AMAZ-AER2HV3.ccdomain.net could not be determined because of this error: Could not get domain controller name from machine EC2AMAZ-AER2HV3.

Node(s) EC2AMAZ-AER2HV3.ccdomain.net cannot reach a writable domain controller. Please check connectivity of these nodes to the domain controllers.

Node(s) EC2AMAZ-AER2HV3.ccdomain.net, EC2AMAZ-PCQP28E.ccdomain.net cannot reach a writable domain controller. Please check connectivity of these nodes to the domain controllers.
```

I have 1 domain controller, 2 member server (joined domain and login with domain user)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the Cluster Validation, my error was:

```
Connectivity to a writable domain controller from node p2.xdba.exagriddba.com could not be determined because of this error: Could not get domain controller name from machine p2.
```

Solution:

```
Server Manager
Local Server
Click on one of the network adapter links, like "Ethernet".
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
Right click on the first network adapter
Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
Properties
Advanced
DNS
Click radio button:
Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected in muiltisite clusters and can be ignored.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4025260/cluster-validation-test-fails-for-multi-site-cluster